# sed step after regular expression

Tags: linux, sed

Can I use a step after finding a line by regex?

for example,

For a file

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

This works,

```
sed '2~2p' -n
B
D
F
```

but this doesn't work

```
sed '/B/~2p' -n
```

I am blamed by unknown command ~

Thanks

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 3):

if you read sed (GNU [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses))'s info/man page, there is **NO** address format like this:

```
/REGEX/~step
```

there are:

- `FIRST~STEP`, which needs two numbers, and
- `ADDR1, ~N` which matches the range between `ADDR1` and the 1st line number(no), that `no%N==0`

I think you were either confused by the two above, or didn't check man page, just thought there "should be" an addr like that.

I guess, you want to do this:

```
kent$  seq 10|sed -n '/2/,${p;n}'
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for step sizes other than 2?

Comment: @tripleee with my limited knowledge of sed, that's probably what I would've done as well but I thought there might be something a bit nicer than that.

Answer (score 0):

awk can do what you're asking, in a more verbose way:

```
seq 20 | 
awk -v pattern="4" -v step=3 '
    !start && $0 ~ pattern {start = NR} 
    start && (NR-start)%step == 0
'
```

```
4
7
10
13
16
19
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could achieve the same thing in awk, in case you're interested:

```
awk '/B/,0 {i++}i%2' file
```

The range operator evaluates to true when the pattern is matched and remains true until the end of the file. While it is true, `i` is incremented and when it is odd, the line is printed.

The version above works well for printing every other line but not for the more general case of every `N` lines. In order to do that, you can modify it slightly like this:

```
awk '/B/,0 {i++} i%N==1' file
```

where `N` is your step.